Meaning of complex number amplitude with exponential decaying signal
I'm studying complex signals and I got curious about complex magnitude(?).
Let's say I have this simple exponential decaying signal.
$$
M e^{-t(A + i\omega)}
$$
$M$ is an amplitude, $t$ is a time, $A$ is a attenuation (or relaxation) coefficient, $\omega$ is a angular frequency ($2\pi f$).
It decays as time goes on.
My question is that if $M$ can be a complex number.
I thought $M$ should be a real number, but it seems there are some examples of complex number $M$.
I know that the $\omega$ affects the phase of the signal.
Then, what is the meaning of the imaginary part of $M$ in this case??

If $M\in\mathbb{C}$, then it can be written in terms of its magnitude and phase: $M = \vert M \vert e^{i\phi}$. This lets us see that the effect of a complex value of $M$ will be to add a phase bias.
